# Reading JSON like other languages in Java

Tags: java, json

I know there are plenty of JSON parsing libraries. 
But after some searching, i can't seem to find a simple way of parsing json data in java.

I know it probably best practice to have a proper model so the api request will map straight to an object.

But lets say i have a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

String id = c.getString("id");
String name = c.getString("name");
String email = c.getString("email");
String address = c.getString("address");
String gender = c.getString("gender");
```

Im used to being able to get the data by using the following syntax:

```
contacts["id]
contacts["name"]
```

Personally i prefer the readability of using the latter, especially when you start getting into nested data such as:

```
articleItem["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["media_details"]["sizes"]["medium"]["source_url"]
```

The java code for getting this data would be really ugly in my opinion.

```
b = a.getJSONObject("_embedded")
c = b.getJSONObject("wp:fea....")
d = c.get(0)
e = d.getJSONObject("media..details")
f = e.getJSONObject("sizes")
g = f.getJSONObject("medium")
h = ............
```

Is a way to do the one liner json in java?

Comment: JsonPath. However, finding a library is off-topic for this site.

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it, thanks!. What do you mean my question if off-topic for this site though?

Comment: I mean there is even a flag which can cause a question to be closed/removed from the site which talks about "questions asking for recommendations in finding a book, library, etc.". Your question doesn't specifically ask for a library, so it's fine, but it is quite close to library request. My remark is just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

[quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=java&gist=1c12d6cbb5d4d3e5eb3ca530da6751bd) will generate your classes and converters directly from JSON sample data; you might consider this 'reading JSON like other languages' in that you'll simply get a POJO instance, and you can access it like:

```java
ArticleItem item = Converter.fromJsonString(jsonString);
String url = item.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedmedia()[0]
    .getMediaDetails().getSizes()
    .getMedium().getSourceUrl();
```

I assumed your JSON is like:

```json
{
  "_embedded": {
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
      {
        "media_details": {
          "sizes": {
            "medium": {
              "source_url": "https://quicktype.io"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the full code that [quicktype generated](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=java&gist=1c12d6cbb5d4d3e5eb3ca530da6751bd):

```java
package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class Converter {
    // Serialize/deserialize helpers

    public static ArticleItem fromJsonString(String json) throws IOException {
        return getObjectReader().readValue(json);
    }

    public static String toJsonString(ArticleItem obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return getObjectWriter().writeValueAsString(obj);
    }

    private static ObjectReader reader;
    private static ObjectWriter writer;

    private static void instantiateMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        reader = mapper.reader(ArticleItem.class);
        writer = mapper.writerFor(ArticleItem.class);
    }

    private static ObjectReader getObjectReader() {
        if (reader == null) instantiateMapper();
        return reader;
    }

    private static ObjectWriter getObjectWriter() {
        if (writer == null) instantiateMapper();
        return writer;
    }
}

// ArticleItem.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class ArticleItem {
    private Embedded embedded;

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    public Embedded getEmbedded() { return embedded; }
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    public void setEmbedded(Embedded value) { this.embedded = value; }
}

// Embedded.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class Embedded {
    private WpFeaturedmedia[] wpFeaturedmedia;

    @JsonProperty("wp:featuredmedia")
    public WpFeaturedmedia[] getWpFeaturedmedia() { return wpFeaturedmedia; }
    @JsonProperty("wp:featuredmedia")
    public void setWpFeaturedmedia(WpFeaturedmedia[] value) { this.wpFeaturedmedia = value; }
}

// WpFeaturedmedia.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class WpFeaturedmedia {
    private MediaDetails mediaDetails;

    @JsonProperty("media_details")
    public MediaDetails getMediaDetails() { return mediaDetails; }
    @JsonProperty("media_details")
    public void setMediaDetails(MediaDetails value) { this.mediaDetails = value; }
}

// MediaDetails.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class MediaDetails {
    private Sizes sizes;

    @JsonProperty("sizes")
    public Sizes getSizes() { return sizes; }
    @JsonProperty("sizes")
    public void setSizes(Sizes value) { this.sizes = value; }
}

// Sizes.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class Sizes {
    private Medium medium;

    @JsonProperty("medium")
    public Medium getMedium() { return medium; }
    @JsonProperty("medium")
    public void setMedium(Medium value) { this.medium = value; }
}

// Medium.java

package io.quicktype;

import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class Medium {
    private String sourceURL;

    @JsonProperty("source_url")
    public String getSourceURL() { return sourceURL; }
    @JsonProperty("source_url")
    public void setSourceURL(String value) { this.sourceURL = value; }
}
```

Comment: ***Edited*** Thanks that looks good, il remember that. Your answer is good and answers the questions so iv marked answers, as the other was just a comment. But using jsonpath i only required 2 lines of code. I would suggest to anyone who reads to use the jsonpath as its very simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper for converting the Json into Java Object which will enabe you to use or parse the data according to your use.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to read a json object in Java as if it was another language, i.e. javascript.

The only way is to convert the json into a Java model object, then accessing it by means of Java stuff.

It is very simple using **Google gson** (https://github.com/google/gson).

In your case, you have to implement all the classes related to the treated json and launch:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Contact contact = gson.fromJson(jsonfile)
```

Obviusly, you have to implement also all the nested Contact class, i.e. Embedded class:

```
public class Contact {
.....
Embedded _embedded;
....
}
```